# Salvar Campos dinâmicos em Meta Box no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou desenvolvendo um tema para o meu site no `Wordpress` e me deparei com uma enorme dúvida. Tentei buscar em vários sites, busquei até em inglês, mas não achei nada do tipo. 
Basicamente é o seguinte, criei um tipo customizado de `post` para publicar tutoriais e nele eu criei uma `meta box` customizada, onde eu preencho com a URL do vídeo e os links úteis da aula. Eu criei um input onde coloco o link da aula e criei uma estrutura onde posso adicionar quantos links úteis para a aula eu quiser, por padrão vem um campo, mas eu criei um jquery, onde pode se adicionar quantos campos quiser. O problema é na hora de salvar isso, o link do vídeo eu consegui salvar de boa, mas os links úteis eu não sei como. Segue abaixo o código

```
            add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'tutoriais_meta_box_add' );

            function tutoriais_meta_box_add() {
                add_meta_box( 'tutoriais-meta-box', 'Informacoes do Tutorial', 'tutoriais_meta_box_cb', 'tutoriais', 'normal', 'high' ); 
            }

            function tutoriais_meta_box_cb(){
                $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
                $video_url = isset( $values['video_url'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['video_url'][0] ) : '';
                wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
                ?>

                    <h2>URL do Video</h2>
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" name="video_url" id="video_url" value="<?php echo $video_url;?>" />
                    </p>

                    <h2>Links Uteis</h2>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        jQuery(function() {
                            var addDiv = jQuery('#addinput');
                            var i = jQuery('#addinput p').size() + 1;

                            jQuery('#addNew').live('click', function() {
                                jQuery('<p><label for="name'+i+'"> Nome </label><input type="text" id="name'+i+'" name="name" value="" placeholder="Link '+i+'" /><label for="link'+i+'"> Link </label><input type="text" id="link'+i+'" name="link'+i+'" value="" placeholder="Link '+i+'" /><label for="tipo'+i+'"> Tipo </label><select id="tipo'+i+'" name="tipo'+i+'"><option value="download">Download</option><option value="acesso">Acesso</option></select><a href="#" id="remNew">Remover Link</a></p>').appendTo(addDiv);
                                i++;
                                return false;
                            });

                            jQuery('#remNew').live('click', function() {
                                if( i > 2 ) {
                                    jQuery(this).parents('p').remove();
                                    i--;
                                }
                                return false;
                            });
                        });
                    </script>

            <div id="addinput">
            <p>
            <label for="name">Nome</label>
            <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1" value="" placeholder="Link 1" />
            <label for="link1">Link</label>
            <input type="text" id="link1" name="link1" value="" placeholder="Link 1" />
            <label for="tipo1">Tipo</label>
            <select id="tipo1" name="tipo1">
                <option value="download">Download</option>
                <option value="acesso">Acesso</option>
            </select>
            <a href="#" id="addNew">Adicionar Link</a>
            </p>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="info_tutoriais">
                <?php
            }

            add_action( 'save_post', 'tutoriais_meta_box_save');

            function tutoriais_meta_box_save( $post_id ){
                if(defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;

                if(!isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' )) return;

                if(!current_user_can( 'edit_post' )) return;

                $allowed = array(
                'a' => array(
                'href' => array()
                )
                );

                if(isset($_POST['info_tutoriais'])){
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'video_url', wp_kses( $_POST['video_url'], $allowed ) );    
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de numerar os inputs dos links, você pode usar **name="links[]"**
Assim você vai receber um array no POST, 
Então você pode salvar esse array em um único post meta usando o implode() ou até mesmo a json_encode(). Quando for usar os dados salvo, você pode usar as funções inversas json_decode() ou explode()